# Sequence concatenation or union when using except operator

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am trying to understand the difference (or lack thereof) between using sequence concatenation or sequence union in this case, so as an example :

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<document>
  <someElement a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4"/>
</document>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="someElement">
    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* except (@c, @d)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* except (@c | @d)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <someElement a="1" b="2"/>
   <someElement a="1" b="2"/>
</document>
```

So I was using xsl:copy with the except operator, as explained on page 261 or Dr. Kay's XSLT and XPath 4th ed. book. There the comma is used to build the sequence.
I also tried with the uninon operator and got the same result.
On page 537, the operators are defined as :

- **,** : Sequence concatenation
- **| union** : Union of two sequences considered as sets of nodes

So when using either, is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `X except Y` selects every node that is in X and is not in Y.

The expressions `(P|Q)` and `(P,Q)` deliver the same nodes, though the results may be in a different order and the second form may include duplicates. But since both forms include the same nodes, they are interchangeable when used on the right-hand side of "except".

Comment: Isn't (P|Q) more efficient than (P,Q)?

Comment: Efficiency depends entirely on the implementation, and it also depends on the sizes of the node-sets concerned. In general, evaluating `(P|Q)` is more work than evaluating `(P,Q)`, but the fact that the result is in document order might save work downstream. An optimizer might quite reasonably rewrite both `X except (P,Q)` and `X except (P|Q)` as `X except P except Q`, in which case they would both perform exactly the same, of course.

Comment: Hm. I thought that since `(P|Q)` contains less information than `(P,Q)` (order, multiplicity) it would be more efficient to use it where the final result is the same anyway. But I guess I don't know how things work under the hood.

Comment: The devil is in the detail. If P and Q are expressions using the child or attribute axis, you can scan the axis and test each node to see if it matches. If they are more complex expressions, for example function calls, you're going to have to sort the results into document order and eliminate duplicates in the case of "|", work that isn't needed in the case of ",".

Comment: Alright. But I still prefer to use `(P|Q)` when I don't care about the order, and reserve the use of `(P,Q)` to cases where I do. I believe that makes the intent of the code more clear.

Comment: It's similar to the fact that people continue to write `author/@name` in preference to `author!@name`. There's a natural tendency to prefer constructs that have been in the language since the beginning, they feel more natural, despite the fact that the newer constructs are actually simpler and potentially faster.

Comment: I don't see how a reason is similar to a tendency.

Answer (score 2):

When you construct a sequence using the **comma operator**, the operands are concatenated in the order that you list them, and the sequence may contain duplicate items.

OTOH, when you use the **union operator**, items are listed in document order and duplicate nodes are eliminated.

Here is a more illustrative example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <alpha/>
    <bravo/>
    <charlie/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <comma>
            <xsl:copy-of select="bravo, alpha, charlie, bravo"/>
        </comma>
        <union>
            <xsl:copy-of select="bravo | alpha | charlie | bravo"/>
        </union>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <comma>
      <bravo/>
      <alpha/>
      <charlie/>
      <bravo/>
   </comma>
   <union>
      <alpha/>
      <bravo/>
      <charlie/>
   </union>
</root>
```

---

***Added:***

In my answer above I chose to ignore the part about the **except** operator and concentrate on the differences between the **comma** and **union** operators when constructing a sequence.

As the other answers pointed out, when the **except** operator is added to the constructing expression, these differences are effectively wiped out.

To demonstrate this in a rather extreme way, the instruction:

```
        <except>
            <xsl:copy-of select="(bravo, alpha, charlie, bravo) except()"/>
        </except>
```

when used in the above example, will produce:

```
   <except>
      <alpha/>
      <bravo/>
      <charlie/>
   </except>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the `except` operator, which is a "set" operator, like `union`, `|` and like `intersect`, it makes no difference as https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#combining_seq states: "All these operators eliminate duplicate nodes from their result sequences based on node identity. The resulting sequence is returned in document order".